# Efficient packing in Gaussian measures on Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces, gaussian, probability-distributions

Let $B(0,1)$ be the unit ball in a separable Hilbert space $H$ with a Gaussian measure $\mu$ on it. For a small $r > 0$, can we have $x_i \in B(0,1)$, $0 < r_i \leq r$ and a constant $K > 0$ independent of $r$ such that the following holds -

1) $B(x_i,r_i) \cap B(x_j,r_j) = \phi$ $\forall i,j$.

2) $B(x_i,r_i) \subset B(0,1)$ $\forall i$.

3)$\sum \mu(B(x_i,r_i)) \geq K\mu(B(0,1))$.